# C# byte arrays questions

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have a couple questions about byte arrays

My first question  this is a byte array correct?
    `byte[] array = {0x90, 0x38, 0x83, 0x49}`

question 2 is would `memorystream.ToArray();`  produce the same as question 1 or am I wrong.

If i am wrong how can i produce question 1 with question 2 or is it not possible?

Thank you

Comment: [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx): "Writes the stream contents **to a byte array**, regardless of the Position property." - So given the MemoryStream's contents are the bytes mentioned, then yes, you would get a byte array with the bytes of q1. And yes, `byte[]` is an array of type "byte" which is commonly referred to as "byte array".

Comment: It would produce the same byte array *if the stream contains those bytes and only those bytes*.

Answer (score 2):

Q1: `byte[] array` is an array of type "byte" which is commonly referred to as "byte array".

Mind that `byte` is an alias for `System.Byte`. So you could come across `Byte[]`, which will also be referred to as "byte array". ( Also mind, that this can be quite different in other languages like Java! )

Q2: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Writes the stream contents to a byte array, regardless of the Position property.

So given the MemoryStream's contents are the bytes mentioned, then yes, you would get a byte array with the bytes of q1.

Comment: Thank you your answer is very helpful

Comment: @user8639393 Welcome to SO. The best way to say "thank you, your answer was helpful" on SO is to upvote it. If it happens to answer your question / solve your problem you can consider to accept it. I recommend not to accept an answer too fast. You could be missing out on better ones if do it at once.